# typescript - a tighter type cannot feed into a looser type?

Tags: typescript, types, interface, typescript-typings

```
const func: (prm: Record<string, string | number>) => void = (prm) => {
    return;
};

interface Obj {
    key1: string;
}

func({ key1: 'value1' } as Obj); // Argument of type 'Obj' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, string | number>'. Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'Obj'.ts(2345)
```

How come the `Obj` object cannot feed into the fuction `func` while `Obj` can fulfill the `prm` required data shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application fails because an object of type `Record<string, string | number>` should have a `string | number` value for any `string` key, which is not the case for `Obj`.

Consider for example this type-correct `func` definition:

```
const func: (prm: Record<string, string | number>) => void = (prm) => {
  const v = prm.someProp
  console.log(v.toLocaleString())
};
```

Given the type of `prm`, a property `prm.someProp` should exist (and it should have a `toLocaleString` method as `string` and `number` do). However, if you call `func` it with an `Obj` argument, it will fail at runtime:

```
func({ key1: 'value1' } as any); // Runtime error
```

You can get the desired type by making `func` generic:

```
const func: <K extends string>(prm: Record<K, string | number>) => void = (prm) => {
  return
};

interface Obj {
  key1: string;
}

func({ key1: 'value1' } as Obj); // No type error
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/N4KABGDGD2B2DOAXMAzArrSAuMAKADgE4C2OASgKYyEAmAPEoQJawDmANGIy62AD5hYaYgCMKhAHwBKMAF4JYAG7QmNOXiLEZ8sKAgQYCZIvWaAdPGjEKABULR84fYcsAbCmdfRWuRWcTQADLQkACG7gDKiMxsuFJSTgC%20ANwgTuiYuMBgANYUAJ4AjDgA5IrhaBSFJWCJYKHw9bD5UslgAPTtYGQYiEzWYOL2hCCJaXpQcEioGNhgdADSgwAeiBSwNI3cbBIEJORU0LSLnNu8AkKi4tJyCsqq6ntat7pOEIQUiGiEsEmpTiw1oQUKFIBQwAB5EQAK1e%20lyBWKXGiPFSEDG6VmWQRRVK5VclWqtXqjSh0NaHS6ADloGBEPl8OChkdRhA0kA)

Comment: very nice and concise explanation. Thank you. However, according to your explanation, I expected that changing the value type  to `string | number | undefined` should fix the issue you pointed out, but it is obvisously not the case. Any thought?

Comment: @mannok That's a little more subtle. Basically you still require a certain type for all possible string properties (which is what the 'index signature' in the error refers to), and the interface does not provide this. Since that's sometimes rather restrictive, literal types support [implicit index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#implicit-index-signatures), meaning it works if you rewrite `Obj` as an interface or surround the object with `{...` and `}`: https://tsplay.dev/WJ5lZm